# Owl Carousel in reverse order is not working IE 10 browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am facing some issues in owl carousel in RTL direction in IE browsers.

Earlier, i have tried it with direction attribute also but doesn't worked.

```
[myExample][1]
```

In  ff & GC browsers, its working as per my requirement. But facing issues IE only.

Regards,
Sopo